# how to extract 1x1 array slice as matrix in R?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, indexing

I am working with 3D arrays.  A function takes a 2D array slice (matrix) from the user and visualizes it, using row and column names (the corresponding dimnames of the array).  It works fine if the array dimensions are > 1.

However, if I have 1x1x1 array, I cannot extract the slice as a matrix:

```
a <- array(1, c(1,1,1), list(A="a", B="b", C="c"))

a[1,,]
[1] 1
```

It is a scalar with no dimnames, hence part of the necessary information is missing.  If I add `drop=FALSE`, I don't get a matrix but retain the original array:

```
a[1,,,drop=FALSE]
, , C = c

   B
A   b
  a 1
```

The dimnames are here but it is still 3-dimensional.  Is there an easy way to get a matrix slice from 1x1x1 array that would look like the above, just without the third dimension:

```
   B
A   b
  a 1
```

I suspect the issue is that when indexing an array, we cannot distinguish between 'take 1 value' and 'take all values' in case where 'all' is just a singleton...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `drop` parameter of `[` is all-or-nothing, but the `abind` package has an `adrop` function which will let you choose which dimension you want to drop:

```
abind::adrop(a, drop = 3)
##    B
## A   b
##   a 1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @thelatemail It's the third odd one for me in the last two days. I think somebody is trying to keep the serial downvote script from noticing. No idea why, though; I've been mostly away for a week.

Answer (score 4):

Without any extra packages, the best I could do was to `apply` and return the sub-array:

```
apply(a, 1:2, identity)
# or
apply(a, 1:2, I)

#   B
#A   b
#  a 1
```